# Message Table, Don't show messages to who deleted

Tags: mysql, sql, messaging, sendmessage

I have a mysql table named messages. It's structure below

```
id | sender_id | receiver_id | message | date | is_receiver_read | conversation_id

1  | 99        | 456         | hello   | 2014 | 1                | 99x456

2  | 456       | 99          | hi)     | 2014 | 0                | 99x456
```

When a sender or receiver delete messages from conversation  i don't want to show to him messages from this conversation. How can do it?

When I add columns which named 'is_sender_delete' and 'is_receiver_delete' there is a problem. For first message sender is 99 but for second message sender is 456. When I update my table after an user press 'delete converstaion button' which column should I update?

If this structure is wrong, what is the alternative solution?

Comment: Can there be more than two parties to a conversation?

Comment: I did not understand you? what you mean two parties?

Comment: That suggests that the answer is no. So just have a separate table called, say, 'blacklist' and store the 'deleted' conversation_id and the user_id there... OR... have a table called subscriptions and store every user and every conversation to which they are subscribed there!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this...

```
CREATE TABLE subscriptions
(user_id INT NOT NULL
,conversation_id INT NOT NULL
,subscribed TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
,PRIMARY KEY(user_id,conversation_id)
);
```